# Php/sqli executed by referencing the link in a send email function?

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli

So i have this page called unsubscribe_process which when given a url query, e.g. www.example.com/unsubscribe_process.php?passkey=123, it will then find and delete the member using mysqli.

The problem I am having is with my unsubscribe.php page. It includes a form and allows the user to put in their email. The form will be submitted, and then an email is sent to the user linking the unsubscribe_process.php page with the specific query and passkey for that user. The hope would be then the user checks their email and clicks the link and then the unsubscribe_process page would remove them from the database.

Back to subscribe.php page, it has no DELETE slqi function anywhere in it, however somehow the user gets deleted after submitted the form. It seems to execute the www.example.com/unsubscribe_process.php?passkey=123 within subscribe.php, without the user having to click on it in the email.

Here is the function that is executed once a user submits their email:

```
 function sendEmail() {
        //enter details into db automatically
            $con = @require './../dbcon.php';
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }
                else
                  {

                  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $_POST['email']);
                  $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
                  $emailindex = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
                if ($email=='')
                {
                echo "<p>No Username has been specified. Please <a href=http://www.example.com/unsubscribe.php> try again.</a></p>";
                }

                //check if username exists in database
                $result = mysqli_query($DB,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE user='". $emailindex ."'") or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $passkey = $row['confirmcode'];

                //if password is set then erase password and send an email to user to update details/create new password.
                if ($row['paid'] ==1){

                $to=$email;
                      $subject="Unsubscribe";
                      $header="from: webmaster@example.com";
                      $message.="You can now unsubscribe yourself in one click with the following link: \r\n";                    
                      $message.="http://www.example.com/unsubscribe_process.php?passkey=$passkey\r\n\r\n";
                      $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
if($sentmail){
            echo "</br><p class='maintextSubmit' align='center'> Please check your email to complete the process.</p>";
            }
            else echo "</br><p class='maintextError' align='center'> An error occurred. Please try again.</p>";
            }
            mysqli_close($DB);
}
}
}
```

SO: Does php execute the link for me when sending the email? This is literally the only reference to the unsubscribe_process.php page anywhere on the subscribe.php page. Why does the unsubscribe_process.php?passkey=$passkey get executed when the email is sent? How can I prevent this from happening (aka only when the link is clicked via the email)? Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to use `isset()`.

Comment: unsubscribe_process is the one calling delete.

Comment: care to explain the isset() use further? This is the function I use to check if the form is submitted and then send the email: if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 
  if (formValid()) {
  sendEmail();
   }

Comment: Which email client are you viewing the sent emails in?

Comment: You're sending a message via a GET method and should be using something of the same nature on checking. In using something like `$passkey = $_GET['passkey']; if(isset($_GET['passkey']) && $passkey==$row['confirmcode']){ // do something }`

Comment: Also using a `WHERE` clause related to the user in question.

Comment: You're also mixing APIs with `or die(mysql_error()`, those `mysql_` functions don't intermix with `mysqli_` functions. This `mysqli_close($DB);` should be `mysqli_close($dbConnection);` just as an added note. But you're using different variables  `$dbConnection` and `$DB` and `$con` something's not right. Plus `$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $_POST['email']);` so it's very hard to say which variable is in fact your DB connection.

Comment: oops was trying to hide my database haha... they are all the same in my file. A little confused on your meaning of $_GET['passkey'].. what is there to get? There is no passkey reference on the subscribe.php page. Only on the unsubscribe_process.php page. Thinking I should just create a form on my unsubscribe_process.php page and if they match the email with the confirm code then it would remove...